# implementing a priority list in recursive tree parsing with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, sorting, priority-queue

I have the following sheet of data (called "WeightsDB", and below line 30 is my formatting sheet with my priority values, named "Formatting":
https://ethercalc.org/zeacfw3jskc3

I have code that recursively parses this data using a scripting dictionary, and generates the following tree:

[[image: WeightsDB[1]]

However, I want my output to be sorted by looking up some priority in the formatting sheet:
[image]

I'm stuck on adjusting my code to handle priority; recursion is already difficult for me. Something to note is that "Cash" entity's should always be at the bottom of every sub-tree. Meaning that if I have an entity that isn't on my formatting sheet, it's priority does not matter AS LONG AS it shows up before cash.

What would the most efficient way of implementing this be, perhaps even nonrecursively?

The code:

```
Sub weightsSheet(wbk, USESTALE, realTimeDataVersion, closeDataVersion)
' Write to "Weights" sheet
    Dim w1 As Worksheet, w2 As Worksheet
    Dim num_rows
    Dim parent As Range, parentName As String
    Dim parentRange As Range, childrenRange As Range
    Dim childCount As Long
    Dim p As Variant
    Dim f1 As Range, f2 As Range
    currRow = 8


    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    ' Real time and close dates
    wbk.Sheets("Weights").Range("D5").Value = "Real-Time (" & realTimeDataVersion & ")"
    realTimeDate = getMaxColumn("WeightsDB", "dataTime", 0)
    wbk.Sheets("Weights").Range("D6").Value = realTimeDate

    If Not IsEmpty(USESTALE) And Not USESTALE = "NULL" Then
        If USESTALE Then
            closeType = "Stale"
        End If
    Else
        closeType = "Close"
    End If

    wbk.Sheets("Weights").Range("E5").Value = closeType & " (" & closeDataVersion & ")"
    closeDate = getMaxColumn("WeightsDB", "dataTime", 1)
    wbk.Sheets("Weights").Range("E6").Value = closeDate

    wbk.Sheets("Weights").Range("K5").Value = closeType & " Exposures"
    Set w1 = wbk.Sheets("WeightsDB")
    Set w2 = wbk.Sheets("Weights")
    num_rows = w1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
    'If there's no parentName column, we can't continue.
    If w1.Rows(1).Find("portfolioName") Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    'find first instance
    Set f1 = w1.Rows(1).Find("portfolioName", lookat:=xlWhole)
    If Not f1 Is Nothing Then
        'find second instance
        Set f2 = f1.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, w1.Columns.Count - f1.Column).Find("portfolioName", lookat:=xlWhole)
        If Not f2 Is Nothing Then
            'set range based on f2
            Set parentRange = w1.Range(f2.Offset(1, 0), _
                                       w1.Cells(Rows.Count, f2.Column).End(xlUp))

        End If
    End If
    'If there's no Root level, how do we know where to start?
    If parentRange.Find("Main") Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    For Each parent In parentRange
        If Not dict.Exists(parent.Value) Then
            childCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(parentRange, parent.Value)
            Set childrenRange = parent.Offset(, 2).Resize(childCount, 1)
            dict.Add parent.Value, Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(childrenRange.Value))
        End If
    Next
    ' Recursive method to traverse our dictionary, beginning at Root element.
    Call WeightsProcessItem("", "Main", dict, w2, 7)
    wbk.Sheets("Weights").Columns("A:F").AutoFit

    Application.CalculateFull 'calculate exposures
End Sub

Private Sub WeightsProcessItem(parentName As String, name As String, dict As Object, ws As Worksheet, row_num As Long, Optional indent As Long = 0)
    Dim output As String, v
    Dim w2 As Worksheet

    'Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.Rept(" ", indent) & name
    Debug.Print parentName & name

    'Formatting
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 3 To 6
        ws.Cells(row_num, i).ClearFormats
        ws.Cells(row_num, i).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        ws.Cells(row_num, i).Font.name = "Calibri"
        ws.Cells(row_num, i).Font.Size = 10
        If i <> 6 Then
            ws.Cells(row_num, i).NumberFormat = "0.0%"
            If parentName = "Main" Or parentName = "Lima" Or name = Papa" Or name = "Main" Then
                ws.Cells(row_num, i).Font.Bold = True
            End If
        End If
        If parentName = "Main" Then
            ws.Cells(row_num, i).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
            ws.Cells(row_num, i).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        End If
        If i = 6 Then
            ws.Cells(row_num, i).Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlDash
            ws.Cells(row_num, i).Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlDash
        End If
        If indent <> 0 Then
            ws.Cells(row_num, i).InsertIndent indent / 1
        End If
    Next

    ws.Cells(row_num, 3).Value = name 'Lets worry about output mapping later

    row_num = row_num + 1
    If Not dict.Exists(name) Then
        'we're at a terminal element, a child with no children.
        Exit Sub
    Else
        On Error GoTo ErrHandler:
            For Each v In dict(name)
                ' ## RECURSION ##
                Call WeightsProcessItem(name, CStr(v), dict, ws, row_num, indent + 2)
            Next
ErrHandler:
       Exit Sub
       Resume Next
    End If

End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Seems like the easiest way is at each level, before you start recursing to the lower levels, sort the nodes based on their priority.

Comment: The thought is interesting, but I'm not sure what order the data would have to be sorted in to be compatible with my recursion... also implementing this seems difficult in VBA without being able to store rows in some datatype.

Comment: Well vba does allow you to create types, so if you felt so inclined... https://stackoverflow.com/a/12414612/2727437

Comment: I want my tree creation to be dynamic, so if I were to create a type I'd have to hard-code some column values, when they could hypothetically change with a new dataset. Could "Insert", be used here? I'm not sure what the logic would look like but cutting horizontal ranges and pushing it like a stack might be a solution

Answer (score 0):

Since VBA collections and for that matter Scripting Dictionaries lack a public "Next" method, I would not use recursion.  Collections are really a modern implementation of the C struct and pointer combination.

I would move the formatting code into a separate sub routine that is called from the `For Each v In dict(name)` loop.  This will also provide you with the ability to add "Cash" at the end of any list.

```
Private Sub WeightsProcessItem(parentName As String, name As String, dict As Object, ws As Worksheet, row_num As Long, Optional indent As Long = 0)
    Dim output As String
    Dim v As Variant

    'Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.Rept(" ", indent) & name
    Debug.Print parentName & name

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler:
    For Each v In dict(name)
        DoFormating name, CStr(v), ws, row_num, indent + 2
        row_num = row_num + 1
    Next
    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub

Private Sub DoFormating(parentName As String, name As String, ws As Worksheet, row_num As Long, Optional indent As Long = 0)
    'Formatting
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 3 To 6
        ws.Cells(row_num, i).ClearFormats
        ws.Cells(row_num, i).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        ws.Cells(row_num, i).Font.name = "Calibri"
        ws.Cells(row_num, i).Font.Size = 10
        If i <> 6 Then
            ws.Cells(row_num, i).NumberFormat = "0.0%"

            If (parentName = "Main") Or (parentName = "Lima") _
                Or (name = "Papa") Or (name = "Main") Then
                ws.Cells(row_num, i).Font.Bold = True
            End If
        End If
        If parentName = "Main" Then
            ws.Cells(row_num, i).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
            ws.Cells(row_num, i).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        End If
        If i = 6 Then
            ws.Cells(row_num, i).Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlDash
            ws.Cells(row_num, i).Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlDash
        End If
        If indent <> 0 Then
            ws.Cells(row_num, i).InsertIndent indent / 1
        End If
    Next

    ws.Cells(row_num, 3).Value = name 'Lets worry about output mapping later
End Sub
```